# How to set width of a serie of element to the width of a image juste before the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the same width to a series of caption, as the image juste before the caption

I have this HTML :

```
<div class="theparent"> 
<img src="pic.jpg"/>
<div class="caption">
        hello
    </div>
<div>
<div class="theparent">
    <img src="pic2.jpg"/>
    <div class="caption">
        hello
   </div>
<div>
<div class="theparent">
<img src="pic3.jpg"/>     
<div class="caption">
        hello
     </div>
<div>
```

All the images have a different width. I want that that every caption has the same width as the picture juste before. 
Important : This width may vary in time, so i think i need to use SetTimeOut

I have try something like :

```
function launchcaption() {
 var myWidth = $(".theparent img").width();
  $(this).next().css( "width", "myWidth" );
}

setTimeout(launchcaption, 10);
```

Please, don"t advise me to use css, in my case, i'm force to use JS. Thanks !

Comment: How about CSS `.caption { width: 100%; }`

Comment: why not use css: .caption{width :100%}

Comment: your code seems to be wrong, missing dot before caption. $(this).find(".caption").css("width", myWidth);

Comment: Aren't divs 100% wide by default? Am I missing something?

Comment: My case is very complex, and i'm force to use js instead of simple like 100% width or something simple like that. But thanks !

Comment: The question's title states "as the image just before the div" while the question description states "as the image just before the caption".

Comment: Why do you need setTimeout? In your case, a plugin like [`imagesloaded`](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) might be a better idea.

Comment: Hi Veverke, sorry if it is unclear, but the caption is a div too !

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `.` on the selector
change this:

```
$(this).find("caption").css("width", myWidth);
```

to this

```
$(this).find(".caption").css("width", myWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks, i have make the correction, but this is not the solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in css. Just set the width of the caption to 100% like this:

```
.caption{
     width: 100%;
}
```

It will automatically get the width of the parent.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, divs are 100% wide by default...unless there is something we're not being told.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$(".caption").each(function(){
    $(this).css("width", $(this).prev('img').css("width"));
});
```

(add the SetTimeOut logic according to your needs...)